# Android Async, interfaces, and onComplete() for handling responses in GUI

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, interface

I have a utility class that will be running an async task using HTTP.  On complete I've setup an interface so I can just fire off methods to process the results (whether it's an activity, fragment, etc.).  This way as long as I implement the interface I can always pass 'this' from wherever I am and it will call the standard onComplete() method to process results when they're available.

My issue is that in most cases I just need one HTTP call so it's straight forward.  What about when I need to do 1,2,3,N HTTP calls in a fragment let's say what will happen when they all complete and go to fire the onComplete() method I set up?

Will the OS queue everything up properly since it's now the main GUI thread and I just have to keep track of a simple counter like numTasks = 0, and each time onComplete() fires just increment so I know when all tasks are done?

And also how do I know which call is completing to handle the different responses accordingly?  I could get back something different from each and need to process accordingly in the same onComplete() method right?  In PHP you can check who called you, is there a way to do that in Java and somehow distinguish between the different instances of the async subclass object I created?  Each time I create this object I'll be storing it as a variable, it'll do it's async stuff, than the onComplete() gets fired from within it for the callback.

```
Fragment <--implements interface for onComplete()
 -instance 1 (implements async) <--pass 'this' as callback
 -instance 2 (implements async) <--pass 'this' as callback
 -onComplete() <---fired from within instance 1 & instance 2 during postExecute()
 -increment task counter++ to know when we're done, but how to differentiate which instance completed and called me to handle response properly?
```

Thanks.

Comment: Would it be best to just pass 'this' to onComplete() from within the async subclass?  Than can I just easily compare objects in java saying onComplete(caller){ if(caller==instance1) }?  This sounds like it would solve the problem?

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface is just a conduit through which Java passes information. Assume that your Fragment class passes its context to your utility class:

```
new Async().executeHTTP(this);
```

In the utility class:

```
public class Async {

    public void executeHTTP(Context context){
        ...
        ((YourInterface)context).onComplete();
    }

}
```

Because you're using the context from your fragment instance, the onComplete() method is only called for that particular instance. The interface creates a conduit between the interface caller and the interface implementation. (In this case, Async instance->Fragment instance.)

If you want to differentiate between different calls from the same instance, just pass in an identifier and pass it back through your onComplete method.

```
new Async().executeHTTP(this, ++requestID);
```

...and in the utility class:

```
public class Async {

    public void executeHTTP(Context context, int id){
        ...
        ((YourInterface)context).onComplete(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes this was useful.  I've matched how Java/android does it with function that returns instance like .setCallback(this) or .setCallback( new Callback()... ) like many other things in android   and the function returns an instance for chaining.  Seems to accomplish the desired effect I need.

Comment: Ah, nice! Glad you got it worked out. Consider upvoting and/or accepting. :)

Comment: I don't see any controls too, I'm new and barely any rep.  I thought I could at least accept or vote on my own stuff..

Comment: You should be able to see a white checkmark near the top of my answer, that's the accept button. Is it not there?

Comment: Sorry, just stupid!  Found it and marked it.  This was exactly what I needed.